# Ionic2 PayPal How to send a Payment?

Tags: angular, paypal, ionic2

I am writing an app using the [Native PayPal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/paypal/) libraries.

I have been looking at the documentation, and it all looks fine, for payments to your own PayPal Account. As you can see here, when PayPal is initialized a client ID associated with your account is used. It receives payment to this account.

```
PayPal.init({
  "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
  "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID"
}).then(() => {
  // Environments: PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork, PayPalEnvironmentSandbox, PayPalEnvironmentProduction
  PayPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
    // Only needed if you get an "Internal Service Error" after PayPal login!
    //payPalShippingAddressOption: 2 // PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal
  })).then(() => {
    let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
    PayPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
```

My app is aiming to allow users to make payments to each other. But My account is the middle-man. It will receive the payment from the sender (minus PayPals fee), take a 1% fee, and make a payment to the receiver. This is the same as the **Uber** model.

**Question**

I can see from the api, that it is possible to receive payments, but how do you send payments?

Will the receiver need to register their card details?

I am not sure what the general plan should be here.

If anyone can offer some advise, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Paypal allows you to do that?, It's not the same person to person payment than person to server - server to person, I don't know the fees for that, paypal slack bot allows you person to person.

Comment: Thank you. I am busy looking at PayPal Slack Bot. Maybe it will do what I need. Just doing some investigation.

Comment: Not sure the best solution is to use a 3rd party (Slack)?